# Is there a standardised questionnaire measuring tendency to think emotionally versus logically?

Tags: social-psychology, emotion, measurement, psychology, rationality

I want to conduct a research on the effect of emotions on decision. It is about the role of affective and cognitive processes in making a decision. I want to know if an individual relies more on emotions or logical thinking, but could not find any validated measure/questionnaire for that. I found some that measures the dual process theory : rational or intuitive but that is not what I am looking for.
Wondering if there is any survey/test for this?

Comment: Hi Potato, Welcome at CogSci. I believe you may have an interesting question, but could you share some initial research you have done yourself already? Moreover, providing a little more context about the study you will be conducting will greatly help people answering your question

Comment: Although this won't answer your question, I do want to challenge you to read contemporary theory on emotion and decision making.  There's an important shift away from the emotion vs. logic/rationality dichotomy.   It doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1):

I studied the *Child and Adolescent participation in decision-making questionnaire* of L. O'Hare, O. Santin, K. Winter, C. McGuinness

They found that children and young people's involvement in decision-making, when it went well, had a four stranded positive ‘therapeutic effect’ in that it led to better child/professional relationships, higher levels of self-esteem in children and young people, increased their sense of mastery and control and reduced their stress and anxiety.

Some items are:

1. Information to make a decision is presented to me in a way I understand
2. I am given the full information to make a decision
3. I feel involved in making decisions in my life
4. I am given the opportunity to weigh up the pros and cons to make a decision
5. I have the ability to weigh up the pros and cons to make a decision

(...) 
I wish this questionnaire will be useful for your research.

**REFERENCES:**

L. O'Hare, O. Santin, K. Winter, C. McGuinness (2016), "The reliability and validity of a child and adolescent participation in decision-making questionnaire", *"Child: care, health and development"*,5,692-698.

LINK :  http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/cch.12369/full